# use dynamic return type in a scala fuction

Tags: scala

I have a function that gets a string with name of model and returning an instance of that case class, but im wondering what is the correct way to use dynamic return type here in this function?

```
case class Person(fname: String, lname: String)
case class Animal(type: String, weight: Double)

def getInstanceOf(model: String): ??? = model match {
    case "person" => Person("jack", "robinson")
    case "animal" => Animal("lion", 190.0)
}
```

thanks!

Comment: You could come up with a base class for all possible output types but then you'll still have to cast to the specific type in order to access type specific methods. In general it's a bad idea to return unrelated types from a single method.

Comment: You can't know information at compile time that doesn't even exist until runtime. Types are a compile-time concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may help to have a bit more context of what the end goal is here to suggest a solution.

If your models all conform to a particular classification and you don't need to know exactly what instance they are then the `abstract class` (or `trait`) suggestion above should work.

EDIT: my original answer included this snippet:

You could also make the return type generic and put a type boundary on it in this scenario, such as:

```
def getInstanceOf[T <: Living](model: String): T = ...
```

But as pointed out below this allows the caller to specify what type they expect which may counteract what is contained in the `model` argument

If you only returned one of two possible types but needed the exact type then maybe an `Either[T1, T2]` would be appropriate here (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) such as:

```
def getInstanceOf(model: String): Either[Person, Animal] = ...
```

But again I think it would be easier to answer if the end goal was explained a bit

Comment: `def getInstanceOf[T <: Living](model: String): T = ...` is bad for this because it says caller gets to choose `T` instead of it depending on value of `model`.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov that's actually a great point. I'll update my answer to call this out

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can define an *abstract class* and extends both classes from it, and then you can specify the abstract class as the return type:

```
abstract class Living

case class Person(fname: String, lname: String) extends Living   
case class Animal(Type: String, weight: Double) extends Living

def getInstanceOf(model: String): Living = model match {
    case "person" => Person("jack", "robinson")
    case "animal" => Animal("lion", 190.0)
}
// getInstanceOf: (model: String)Living
```